# Sitecore Analytics redirecting multisite solution

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

I have a multi-site solution with analytics enabled. When a user visits one of the other sites, it seems the analytics engine is redirecting the user to a different site.

I've read [here](http://blog.blacktambourine.com.au/post/128307243250/sitecore-analytics-redirect-issues) that this can be caused by the `Analytics.HostName` containing the host for the site that the user is being redirected to. However, this setting is empty.

Here are the request and response headers:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is associated to the setting "Analytics.HostName" in "Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config" file. You should leave this empty in a multisite solution.

Comment: This was actually empty, but another file was patching it in. Strangely `showconfig.aspx` said the source was `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config` but it wasn't!

Comment: Hey Dmytro, I had the same issue explained by David and sitecore support suggested the solution was to empty this value -because of multisite and you can't set multiple values. I did and solved it straight away. Sitecores' support answer was as follow:
`Analytics.HostName is a value of the global address (e.g. www.domain.com). This value should be the same for all CDs.
But please note that for the multi-site solution the value should be blank (for all CDs).
For more details please see the following known issue:
https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/792020`